# Safari 6.0.2 not calling onaudioprocess

Tags: html, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I've earlier successfully used the *JavaScriptAudioNode* in the Web Audio API to synthesize and mix audio both in Chrome and Safari 6.0. However, the latest version of Safari no longer appears to work, because it does not call *onaudioprocess* to fill the source buffers.

This is a simplified example which plays only silence and appends text to the document body on each call to *onaudioprocess*:

```
<html>
<head>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {    
    var context = new webkitAudioContext(); 
    var mixerNode=context.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 0, 2);                

    mixerNode.onaudioprocess=function(ape) {                     
      var buffer=ape.outputBuffer;
      for(var s=0;s<buffer.length;s++)
      {  
        buffer.getChannelData(0)[s]=0;      
        buffer.getChannelData(1)[s]=0;       
      }
      $("body").append("buffering<br/>");
    };               

    $("body").html("");               
    mixerNode.connect(context.destination);               
    return false;
  });                                                          
});                         
</script>    
</head>  
<body>  
<a href="#">start</a>        
</body>  
</html>
```

The above example works in Chrome as expected, but not in desktop Safari. The iOS version of Safari does not work either, but it never did work for me in the first place.

Calling *context.createJavaScriptNode* does return a proper object of type *JavaScriptAudioNode* and connecting it to the destination node does not throw any exceptions. *context.activeSourceCount* remains at zero, but this is also the case in Chrome as it apparently only counts active nodes of type *AudioBufferSourceNode*. *context.currentTime* also increments as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this an actual bug or a missing feature in Safari? The Apple documentation has no mention of *JavaScriptAudioNode* (nor the new name, *ScriptProcessorNode*) but it did work before on the first release of Safari 6. The iOS Safari requirement for user input doesn't seem to help, as the example above should take care of that.

The simple example can be found [here](http://mod.haxor.fi/webaudiotest.html) and a more complex one is my [Protracker module player](http://mod.haxor.fi/) which exhibits the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple bugs in Safari's implementation of the Web Audio API that you'll need to look out for. The first is in the `createJavaScriptNode` constructor... it seems to have problems with the "input channels" param being set to 0. Try changing it to this:

```
createJavaScriptNode(2048, 1, 2)
```

The second issue has to do with garbage collection (I think); once your mixerNode variable is out of scope, Safari seems to stop firing the `onaudioprocess` callback. One solution is to introduce mixerNode at the top-level scope (i.e. declaring `var mixerNode;` at the top of your script) and then store your JavaScriptNode in that top-level variable. If you plan on dynamically creating multiple mixerNodes, you can achieve the same effect by storing references to them in a top-level array variable.

If you make these two changes (input channel param set to 1, maintaining a reference to the mixerNode) then your script should work in Safari as expected.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer - implementing the changes you suggested did indeed fix the problem with Safari.

Comment: wow, never would've figured it out without this answer. cheers!

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure I'm having the exact same issue in canary 30.0.1564.0. onaudioprocess stops getting called *right after* a GC pass (observed using the DevTools timeline tab). Attaching stuff to the global scope as suggested is an effective workaround. Thanks Matt for putting me on the right track

Comment: I had the exact same problem in Chrome 30.0.1599.101 (Official Build 227552) on Windows.  Declaring my variables containing nodes outside of a callback caused everything to function as expected!

Comment: The garbage collection problem also exists in Chrome (at least in Mac). This means, you must keep a reference to the JavaScript node. Otherwise, after a few seconds of successful onaudioprocess call, system will stop calling the callback. Potentially a very difficult problem to debug, but thanks to this answer, I could fix the problem.