# Alternative to createScriptProcessor on Safari?

Tags: ios, html, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I have created an app in HTML 5 that generates white noise on its own using an ScriptProcessorNode. All is working fine for Google Chrome on my Mac and also in my Android phone (not to mention that the performance is really bad on my Xperia Acro S) but it is not working in Safari neither Google Chrome for iOS.

Is there an alternative for this node?

I need to create sound samples on the fly... Probably if this work I would add a filter node to filter the white noise for generating other sounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Safari, try `createJavaScriptNode` with the same arguments as `createScriptProcessor`.

The spec changed was changed a while ago, and older versions of Safari are still using the old method name.

Comment: I guess I am using the last version of Safari... I will try that and tell you! Thanks!

Comment: It is not working on Safari... This is the part of the code where I assign the context and the script:                               window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  context = new AudioContext();
  
  if(this.context.createScriptProcessor)
  {
   jsProcessor = context.createScriptProcessor(512, 0, 2);
   alert("Chrome Desktop/Android");
  }
      else if(this.context.createJavaScriptNode)
      {
     jsProcessor= context.createJavaScriptNode(512,0,2);
     alert("Safari");
  }
        else
        {
         alert("No way");
         
       }

Comment: The last comment is what I finally have in my html. I am considering the different browsers and the alerts are shown. The problem is that in Safari (iOS or MAC) I can not hear anything...

Comment: Hmm. Can you post an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I have also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087119/use-scriptprocessornode-in-iphone-safari. But also with no luck on my iPod Touch 5th with iOS 6.1.2

Comment: I have created an account in JSFiddle and posted my code... Here is the link so you can help me: http://jsfiddle.net/leo2_uru/G5j5R/1/ It is not working on the page but maybe it could help you to see my code. Thanks!

Comment: Safari on iOS requires the AudioContxt be created in response to a user interaction (i.e. tap a button to start), which is probably why it is not working.